# MongoDb: How to drop a database using shell using authentication?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have a authenticated user with all required privileges to drop a database. I want to drop the database from the shell and tried following command

```
mongo -uuser -ppass newdb --eval "db.dropDatabase();"
```

I got following:-

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: newdb
[object Object]
```

That's it I got no errors and no results. The database still exists with all values.

Comment: Currently you would be on the "test" database unless you specified something else to connect to. Also you don't state an error or what happened/didn't happen in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Your command should work

```
mongo -uuser -ppass newdb --eval "db.dropDatabase();"
```

If you access to mongo after that with

```
mongo -uuser -ppass newdb
```

The database is created again but empty, so when you said:

> The database still exists with all values.

Are you sure that has all collections inside ?

To check if has been deleted you can do:

```
mongo -uuser -ppass
> show dbs
```

The "newdb" shouldn't appear.

I've tested it with Mongo 2.4.2.

Comment: what is uuser is it a typo of user ?

Comment: No, the first "u" is the command param `-u` , i.e: `mongo -ujohn -pjohn_pass`

Comment: using -u user is invalid ?

Comment: No, you can pass the param in both ways (with and without whie-space). I use this format in my answer because is the format used in the original question.

Comment: I just test both case it still throw authentication error when using with eval

Comment: Ok, I'd need more context to be sure, but the problem is yout MongoDB config for auth, try to add this param `--authenticationDatabase=admin`  before the dbname

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
mongo -u USER -p PASS --eval "db=db.getSiblingDB('DB_NAME');db.dropDatabase();"
```

Reference:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/